# Powershell Script to check process memory on multiple remote computers

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and working on a script that will check the memory usage of a process on 4 remote computers. The process that it checks has 3 instances on each computer so I have a script that will sum the memory for the 3 instances on each remote computer and output it. If the sum of memory reaches over 6000MB on one of the computers, it will send an email with the output (Haven't got to that code yet). The issue is that the output of the memory for each computer is displaying the memory of the first computer. Below is my script.

```
$process = "Example Process"
$computers = @("Computer1", "Computer2", "Computer3", "Computer4")
foreach($computer in $computers){
    $procs = Get-Process -Name $process |
      Group-Object -Property Name -NoElement |
        Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1} |
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Computer=$computer
                Count=$_.Count
                Name=%_.Name
                'Memory Sum in MB' = [math]::Round((Get-Process -Name $_.Name |
                    Measure-Object WorkingSet -sum).sum /1MB, 3)
$procs
```

The above code gives me the output below. 2210.245MB is the memory usage on Computer1 but is displaying for all 4.

```
 Computer     Count     Name        Memory Sum in MB
----------   ------    ------      -----------------
Computer1      3     Example Process  2210.245
Computer2      3     Example Process  2210.245
Computer3      3     Example Process  2210.245
Computer4      3     Example Process  2210.245
```

My desired output would be

```
 Computer    Count     Name        Memory Sum in MB
----------   ------    ------      -----------------
Computer1      3     Example Process  2210.245
Computer2      3     Example Process  3994.358
Computer3      3     Example Process  4170.236
Computer4      3     Example Process  2774.681
```

Thanks,

Comment: I do not see anything in the code that uses `$computer` to run on a remote machine. I think this is all happening on your local machine. Using `help Get-Process`, the `-Module` parameter description talks about using `Invoke-Command`.